# Translating an FFmpeg Command to ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I have an audio file with 2 channels. I was able to separate the channel audio using the below command. I’m trying to translate an FFmpeg command to use with the `ffmpeg-python` library. The original command is:

`ffmpeg -y -i 'input.mp3' -map_channel 0.0.0 'left.wav' -map_channel 0.0.1 'right.wav'`

This command takes an input audio file (input.mp3), and splits it into two output files (left.wav and right.wav), each containing one channel of the input.

Here’s my attempt to translate this command to `ffmpeg-python`:

```py
import ffmpeg

input_file = 'input.mp3'
output_file_left = 'left.wav'
output_file_right = 'right.wav'

# Create separate streams for left and right channels
stream_left = ffmpeg.input(input_file).output(output_file_left, map='0.0.0')
stream_right = ffmpeg.input(input_file).output(output_file_right, map='0.0.1')

# Run the commands separately
ffmpeg.run(stream_left)
ffmpeg.run(stream_right)
```

This script creates separate streams for the left and right channels and runs them separately. However, I get below error:

```
Stream map '0.0.0' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.
```

I’m not sure if I'm doing right. Kindly help.

Comment: You must use exactly the same option names as given in the original command: i.e. `map_channel='0.0.0'`. (The `map` option selects streams rather than channels and requires different syntax).